# Got stuck thinking in an idea that i got

Tags: c#

First of all, sorry that I was unable to give a proper title.
I got stuck with an idea that's been with me today almost the whole day after searching and searching and searching, till it came to a point that I decided to ask it on Stackoverflow!

So here's where I am stuck:

(I am making an auto-installer currently coded in C# and it is Dutch. It works really awesome but I just need one thing to finish my base. For example:

- You have 'multiple' objects selected in a checklistbox, those are read from the checklistbox itself, they get trimmed and they get launched after that.

Now that's all working, I wanted to add a waiting method, for example we got:

- Malwarebytes & CCleaner as installation 'example'.

Now when both are checked, and I click start, it starts both of the programs.
What I want to do is: to tell the program to start one program, do your thing, once its finished (closed) it should go to the next.

But... There is a problem, my programs are started in an array, so it basically works if there are multiple objects checked, than it will start all of the checked objects. And I really have no idea how to reach the same thing which is basically :

- If there are multiple objects selected, start the object(s), do your thing(auto-clicking etc.),once its closed and confirmed its closed, move on to the next object and do the same thing until its been completed. I would like to make it work with a progressbar, but never really looked into a progress bar as they seem confusing.

I have a piece of code that finds the Process ID so maybe I can do something with that, but the Process ID is never the same on the applications that I start, so when they start in an array I got kinda of an issue.

Could someone help me please figuring out what & how to code / do this?

here's the code i use to make this work :

```
                string pad = Application.StartupPath;

            foreach (string checkedItem in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                if (checkedItem.Contains("."))
                {
                    string str = checkedItem;
                    if (str.Contains("."))
                    {
                        int index = str.IndexOf('.');
                        string folder = str.Substring(0, index);
                        try
                        {
                            bool started = false;
                            var process = new Process();
                            process.StartInfo.FileName = pad + "/data/" + folder + "/" + checkedItem;
                            started = process.Start();
                            var processID = process.Id;
                            var processNAAM = process.ProcessName;
                            textBox1.Text += "Gevonden - ID: " + processID + "     NAAM: " + processNAAM + Environment.NewLine;
                            textBox1.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) + "  -  " + "Installatie Keuze wordt opgestart." + Environment.NewLine;
                            process.WaitForExit();

                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: How are you starting the programs? Are you using the Process.Start method? If so, you could use Process.WaitForExit() to, well, wait for exit, before launching the new one. See...http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start

Comment: my program works with Process.Start, however its bound to its checklistbox who basicly works if there is a check listed above >0 than execute it, so even tho if i do process.waitforexit, it will still run 2 of the selected ones or multiple.

Comment: Please post the code that goes over the checkboxlist and launches the processes. There's no reason it should launch two concurrently.

Comment: added code, sorry if some of it is confusing, its writtin in dutch but i think you can figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can make the code simpler and shorter by using the CheckedListBox's [CheckedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx) property. Secondly, there's no point to all your copying of strings from one to another. Strings are immutable in .NET - they never change. You can keep just one copy and cut from there.

Next, you can use the methods in [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) to cut the filename without the extension, or to build a full path without worrying about having too many or too few "/"'s.

Third, for your original question - just call `WaitForExit` on your `Process` object to make it wait before moving on with the list of processes.

Thirdly

```
foreach (string checkedItem in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
   if (checkedItem.Contains("."))
   {
       string baseName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(checkedItem);
       string processPath = Path.Combine(pad, "data", baseName, checkedItem); 
       Process process = Process.Start(processPath);
       process.WaitForExit();
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 For making the code much much simpler and less prone to bugs.

Comment: looks about the same as what i got right now. it works that way but i wonder where to put my 'soon to be coded' code area where it launches the module(s) to press start or cancel etc.

Comment: System.IO.Path.Combine takes two arguments because that's how they designed it, so for that reason i havent used Path.Combine

Comment: @user1547355 As you are using .NET 3.0, chain multiple `Path.Combine(string, string)` calls, it will be much safer than rolling your own path handling.

Comment: New code in originial source of text above, does that look alot better?

Comment: Thank you @Lukazoid, & Avner Shahar-Kashtan

Comment: @user1547355 If you found what I did useful, could I possibly have an upvote? (cheeky I know)

Comment: vote up requires 15 reputation else i would, i only have 3 =(

Answer (score 0):

After the line where you start the process (`process.Start()`), simply add the following:

```
process.WaitForExit()
```

This will pause the containing thread until the target process has exited.

Comment: Once i did that, it wouldnt run my 2nd program wich is kinda not ment to be as i asked the program to launch 2 programs.

Comment: Once the first program has exited, it will launch the second program

Comment: it has exited, it would not launch the second

Comment: Try surrounding the code which launches the process with a try { } catch { } block and see if there are any exceptions raised, this may be causing your loop to exit and stop processing any additional options.

Comment: Also take a look at the answer provided by @avner-shahar-kashtan. It shows how much simpler the code could be made, while reducing the chance for potential bugs.